# How to make only one service layer for all request in react js?

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-thunk

I want make a universal service layer that handle all the request in reactjs.

Here is the code i have done so far:

This is the thunk action from which the service layer. postRequest method get all the parameters that it need to call an api.

bankCustomerThunkAction.js

```
    export const fetchBankCustomers = (filterType, searchParam) => dispatch => {
apiServices.postRequest(urlBuilders.getUrlAppenderWithParams(bankCustomerApiConstant.GET_BANK_CUSTOMER_STATISTICS, "filter", filterType), searchParam).then((response) => dispatch(actions.getBankCustomerStatisticsWithDate(response))).catch(error => console.log("error", error))
```

}

this is the only service layer from which the backend api is requested

service.js

```
 export const postRequest = (url, data) => Axios({method: 'POST' , url:url , data : data})
```

Is it sufficent to make this or there are other alternatives?

Comment: It all depends on your use case, you may want to add user token to headers from local storage or cookies.

Comment: Since i am using axios i can add header to  it and make it global
const dashboardAxiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://10.13.209.69:8080/dashboard/api/dashboard' });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it is right, I guess.

I can give a little suggestion, that will help when you need different header for a particular request.

That is,

> bankCustomerThunkAction.js -> DataService.js -> service.js

bankCustomerThunkAction.js

```
dataService.bankCustomerThunkAction().then().catch()
```

DataService.js -> Here you can header code, or any optional params code

```
export bankCustomerThunkAction ()=>apiServices.postRequest(urlBuilders.getUrlAppenderWithParams(bankCustomerApiConstant.GET_BANK_CUSTOMER_STATISTICS, "filter", filterType), searchParam).then((response) => dispatch(actions.getBankCustomerStatisticsWithDate(response))).catch(error => console.log("error", error))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: I cant since i have only 8 reputation

Comment: oh np, its okay!